# S3 upload with presigned URLs and CORS Issue

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, axios, pre-signed-url

I am uploading files from my react app to S3 using Pre Signed URLs the Bucket it self is private and only enabled CORS for all domains (for the dev env).

How ever when the axios post tries to upload a file i am seeing the No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header present Error. The pre-flight options request is throwing this error.

I am trying this from my local machine.

Here is the CORS Configuration i have. I have tried the wild card '*' for AllowedOrigin with no luck.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>300000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Possibly not the whole problem, but use `<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>` until you get CORS working correctly, and only change this value if desired, after that.

Comment: Changed the <AllowedHader> value to * and still having the same Issue.

Comment: did you get this resolved? im having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that the service that is creating the pre-signed url isn't valid. In my scenario the bucket was on `eu-centar-1` but the pre-signed-key had `us-east-1` in the url. I fixed my service for creating the pre-signed-key and it worked. It wasn't connected to origin. Check if this is ok in your scenario

Answer (score -1):

I was running into this issue and added an explicit `Content-Type` header with a value of `application/octet-stream`. I got this solution from referencing this post on uploading to s3 with a presigned url [using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59537252/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-a-pre-signed-url-in-aws-using-node-js-and-axios).