# How do I upload a file to a pre-signed URL in AWS using Node.js and Axios?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, axios

I have next scenario:

1. Generate a signed URL for file upload by AWS-SDK
2. Try to upload a local file using Axios (or request) npm package

But every time I have an error:

Status: **403**
statusText: **Forbidden**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>FakeKeyId</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>PUT

application/json;charset=utf-8
1577742550
/test-bucket-super/xxx/test.mp3</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>DAAOZ0/VkMNEMMlGkRUsSuRO3J4=</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>50 55 54 0a 0a 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 6a 73 6f 6e 3b 63 68 61 72 73 65 74 3d 75 74 66 2d 38 0a 31 35 37 37 37 34 32 35 35 30 0a 2f 74 65 73 74 2d 62 75 63 6b 65 74 2d 73 75 70 65 72 2f 78 78 78 2f 74 65 73 74 2e 6d 70 33</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>CBD3F1D0D02EA874</RequestId><HostId>LPu+RQ8otcljI1Wt5FiZm+UmTFNiCX+2HyGtN0kTAugLiT21M55DtbzQdF/s7qOCSaZvzTp4kw4=</HostId></Error>
```

```
const axios = require('axios');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: 'FakeKeyId',
    secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    region: 'eu-west-1'
});

const fs = require('fs');
const readFile = require('util').promisify(fs.readFile);

(async () => {
    try {
        const presignedS3Url = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
            Bucket: 'test-bucket-super',
            Key: 'xxx/test.mp3'
        });
        const file = await readFile('./SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3');

        const axiosResponse = await axios.put(presignedS3Url, {
            data: file,
        });
        console.info(axiosResponse)
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
})();
```

But I managed to upload the file via cURL

```
curl -X PUT -T ~/Downloads/SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3 'https://test-bucket-super.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxx/test.mp3?AWSAccessKeyId=FakeKeyId&Expires=1577741900&Signature=9kPiC%2B85SEFp6g5C3nwEWe4TueU%3D' -v
```

Comment: do you still need help

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The issue here is, axios for some reason adding a default `Content-Type: application/json` header. thats the reason why the signature is failing to match. I am not sure how to remove the header.

But following works for me where I am including the `content-type` during the signature generation. Also I am including the same header when using it.

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const presignedS3Url = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
      Bucket: 'bucket-name',
      Key: 'car.jpg',
      ContentType: 'application/octet-stream'
    });
    const file = await readFile('./car.jpg');

    const axiosResponse = await axios.put(presignedS3Url, {
      data: file,

    }, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
      }
    });
    console.info(axiosResponse)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
})();
```

Comment: Glad to be of help

Comment: This is how to remove content type from a request: {headers: { 'Content-Type' :  '' }}

Comment: Shouldn't the second argument in axios.put just be `file` instead of `{ data: file }`? Otherwise it uploads a JSON object with the contents of the buffer.

Comment: Double-check this above comment @openam, Thanks buddy it saves my day.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Axios will default to **application/json** Content-Type if it's not declared. You might find it useful to immediately clear the Content-Type header upon creating your Axios instance:

```
const axios = Axios.create()
delete axios.defaults.headers.put['Content-Type']
```

Answer (score -1):

Your request needs to match the signature, exactly. One apparent problem is that you are not actually including the canned ACL in the request, even though you included it in the signature. Change to this:

```
var options = { headers: { 'Content-Type': fileType, 'x-amz-acl': 'public-read' } };
```

Comment: I don't see any canned ACL in the original question.